# What is the best way to couple diffuse light into a single-mode fiber?

Tags: lenses, fiber-optics

I understand the requisites to couple a laser beam into a single-mode fiber, including mode-field diameter and numerical aperture. However, when trying to couple diffuse light into a single-mode fiber, I guess a very low component of the field will fulfill the requirements for propagation when the fiber is put in "direct contact" with the source.

What role can a coupling lens or lenses play in getting more light into the fiber? Could I get more light than from butt-coupling? Would that be only because I could catch light from a larger area and focus it on the fiber?

I am working with light coming out of a diffusive medium. If I could get more light even from a bigger area, I would be interested in not catching more than one speckle.

Answer (score 0):

Butt coupling will give you the easiest practical result. But also beware of cladding modes, or modes that propagate a short distance.

If you don’t really need single mode at the output, you will collect  significantly more light even with a few  more modes. But if a coherent source those modes may interfere.

The single fiber core is quite small, 8-10 um,   Multi mode fiber is often 50 or 62.5 um in diameter so that should be smaller than your speckle pattern in most situations I think.

Comment: Yes, I am interested in a single mode at the output, so that there is no decorrelation going on in the fiber (that's also the reason not to get more speckles). The problem is I need more power coupled into the fiber than what I get with butt coupling. How can I do this? (This is what I thinking when I wrote "best way" in the question, i.e. more light)

Comment: Without knowing the details of the setup I think you are limited by the etendue. https://www.energetiq.com/etendue-and-optical-throughput-calculations . The problem is single mode really is single mode . Having a antireflection coating on the fiber tip or index matching the fiber tip helps a tiny bit.  If you can modulate or chop your light source that can help by allowing you to use a better signal recovery technique. Same with choosing a light source that matches your detector response. Or chose a better detector and doing photon counting.

Comment: To get an idea if lens would help you could set up a spatial filter with a pinhole and see how much light you get through a pinhole similar to the diameter of your fiber core.  Also if you really want single mode at the output of your fiber you may want to use a long fiber and mode scramble the fiber to lose the higher modes.